# How do I validate multiple checkboxes, using Statamic forms?

Tags: statamic

I'm using Statamic CMS

I've got a checkbox group with two checkboxes, I'd like both of them to be checked before the form will submit.

Setting the field as 'required' half works. The form will error if nothing is checked, but it submits if one of the boxes is ticked.

I can see under the validation tab, there's a list of additional rules. But I'm not sure which rule to use.

If it helps, this is what the HTML checkbox group looks like:

```
<div>
    <label>Contact permissions</label>
    <span>Please tick both checkboxes</span>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="gdpr" />
        Please contact me with the details I've provided
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes[]" value="terms" />
        I agree with the <a href="#">terms and conditions</a>
    </label>
</div>
```

I'm using the `{{ fields }}` tag to generate the HTML

Within the CMS, under the validation tab, there's a link to the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required-with). As I want to validate two checkboxes, I think I need the required_with: rule, but I can't get it to work...

required_with: is looking for two values, the example shows this:

```
required_with:foo,bar,..
```

The values of the checkboxes are, `value="gdpr"` and `value="terms"` so I (wrongly) assume this should work...

```
required_with:gdpr,terms
```

After saving the changes and testing the form, it still submits? Even though only one of the checkboxes might be ticked...

What is the correct syntax/values to use to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

:) `foo,bar` in the docs are field names in your form. What you're doing with `gdpr,terms` are values.

Plus, since both your buttons are named `checkboxes[]`, the form is validating that if either one is selected, then it should be passed. Hopefully this helps!